# Safely echo python commands into file without executing them

Tags: python

So I have a python file with a ton of lines in it that I want to read into python then echo into another file over a socket.

Assuming I have file foo.py

```
import os
os.popen('some command blah')
print("some other commands, doesn't matter")
```

Then I try and open the file, read all the lines, and echo each line into a new file.

Something along the lines of

```
scriptCode = open(os.path.realpath(__file__)).readlines()
for line in scriptCode:
    connection.send("echo " + line + " >> newfile.py")
print("file transfered!")
```

However, when I do this, the command is executed in the remote shell.

**So my question:**

How do I safely echo text into a file without executing any keywords in it?

**What have I tried?**

- Adding single quotes around line
- Adding single quotes around line and then a backslash to single quotes in line

**Things I've considered but haven't tried yet:**

- Base64 encoding the line until on the remote machine then decoding it (I don't want to do this because there's no guarentee it'll have this command)

**I know this is odd. Why am I doing this?**

- I'm building a pentesting reverse shell handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) will:

> Return a shell-escaped version of the string s. The returned value is a string that can safely be used as one token in a shell command line, for cases where you cannot use a list.

Much safer than trying to quote a string by yourself.

Comment: Note that it's identical to: `"'" + line.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'"` and that `shlex.quote` was only added in Python 3.3.

Comment: @alex-taylor works like a charm.  (though I did `from pipes`) Thanks